# How to add a footnote mark next to author name

Tags: footnotes, acm, author, author-number, acmart

I need to add a mark (e.g., a star) next to an author name and a footnote with this mark at the bottom. Something similar to `\footnote` but at the author name.

I use an ACM format article. I found some previous posts suggest using `\thanks` but this does not add a mark next to the author's name.

How to add a mark as a superscript to author's name and this mark also shown to the footnote?

Here is my script using \thanks which adds a footnote but not mark or number attached to it:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{footnote}   

\begin{document}

\author{Author}
\thanks{First author.}
\affiliation{
    \institution{Uni.}
    \city{C}
    \country{C}}
\email{xyz@mail.com}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Section1}
Section.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document class you are using has a built in function for that, check out the manual at http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acmart/acmart.pdf

If you want the affiliation to appear under each author you use the `\affiliation` command, (in order: `\author`, `\orcid`, `\affiliation` `\email`).

If you want the affiliation to be in a footnote (with a footnote sign) you replace the `affiliation` command with `\additionalaffiliation`. If you do that make sure you put the email inside the affiliation block.

If you need just anote (like thanks) you can use `\authornote`.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{footnote}   

\begin{document}

\author{First Author}
\authornote{some other note}

\additionalaffiliation{
    \institution{Uni 1.}
    \city{City1}
    \country{Country1}
    \email{xyz@mail.com}   
     }


\author{Second Author}

\additionalaffiliation{
    \institution{Uni 2.}
    \city{City2}
    \country{Country2}
    \email{abc@mail.com}  
     }



\title{Title}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract ...
\end{abstract}

\section{Section1}
Section.
\end{document}
```